# Using Sync Framework to sync individual rows

Tags: .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a requirement to sync remote databases to a central database, but the customer wants to be able to choose with rows of data is synched.  For example, if there is a table with 5 rows, the user wants "checkbox functionality" to say only sync rows 1, 4, and 5.

I don't believe Sync Framework does this out of the box. I have only seen where the entire table is synched with a central database.

Is there a way to tell the Sync Framework to sync individual rows of a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to filter rows, this is built into all of the sync framework's SQL providers. This MSDN page covers filtering: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928701(v=sql.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928701%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

If it will be as simple as a checkbox to turn rows on/off you can probably just add a bit/boolean field to the table and use that column in the filter clause. Otherwise, you can use data that is relevant to your application - such as the MSDN sample where only sales data for a particular region will be synced.